# Using Eth-Brownie to fork mainnet from specific blockheight?

Tags: blockchain, ganache, state-trie, blockchain-fork, state

Can I use eth-brownie to fork mainnet from a specific blockheight?

I have an archive node if that helps. I want to see what would have happened, instead of what will happen

Can another service do this?